# Foley artist leather toolkit!

Tags: foley, foley-artist, sound-design, sound-effects

Good morning from Greece guys! I was surfing the internet today and i found something very interesting indeed! A toolkit created for foley artists dedicated for making the classic Swoosh, thud, bash, shwud sounds we see in movies so much.

I havent't found where you can order this beautiful hand made toolkit but i think anyone can build his own easily if you can find different kind of leather skins.

I post it here cause i think many will find this project interesting! Enjoy!
Original site here: [Chiara Onida](http://chiarao.blogspot.com/p/work.html)

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how well known this tip is, but some foley artists i've met use Mr Sheen (furniture polish, not the actor) to make the leather extra creaky.

Comment: seems the internet is flowing with Sheens hahahah. Is that Mr Sheed a spray polish Roger? (Cause we don't have that thing here)

Comment: @Nikos Actually, i think it's just an Australian thing, although i'm pretty sure you could find alternate products. It's basically an aerosol furniture/floor polish.

Answer (score 1):

This is cool! Fantastic and unusual combination of sound and design....

Answer (score 0):

Looks cool.  The guy has some interesting sound-related items, including a "dictionary of sound" where he tries to put into onomatopoeic words the sounds an item can make.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this isn't something that's commercially available. It looks to be more of a student project based on the info from the site.

It's still a really neat idea. The tools will eventually become less and less easy to get variation out of, and will eventually only be useful for doing sounds in sync but even at that point I'm sure you can still get some great sounds out of it if used creatively.